# Upload file in IE9 is failing using ng-file-upload + Spring MVC + OAuth2.0

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, ng-file-upload

I'm completely dummy in AngularJS and appreciate your help here.

I'm trying to implement a file upload page. It is very simple, user selects the file and pushes upload button and it has to be uploaded to back-end which is a Spring MVC REST web service. I'm trying to use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

Here is my front-end code:

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file
      accept="application/pdf" ngf-max-size="2MB" required 
      ngf-model-invalid="errorFiles">
   <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
   <i ng-show="myForm.file.$error.maxSize">File too large
    {{errorFiles[0].size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 2M</i>
<button ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="uploadFiles(picFile)">Submit</button>
```

and controller:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function(file, errFiles) {
            console.log("Uploading files");
           $scope.f = file;
           $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
           if (file) {
               file.upload = Upload.upload({
                   url: 'api/proposals/upload',
                   data: {file: file}
               });

               file.upload.then(function (response) {
                   $timeout(function () {
                       file.result = response.data;
                   });
               }, function (response) {
                   if (response.status > 0)
                       $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
               }, function (evt) {
                   file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                                            evt.loaded / evt.total));
               });
           }
       };
```

and my back-end:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/proposals/upload",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<TemporaryProposal> 
   uploadProposal(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile agreementFile){
```

The error I'm getting in IE9 console is

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'error': object is null or undefined
```

and from back-end:

```
[DEBUG] com.iocs.portal.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Mar 01 08:53:23 EST 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={message=Access is denied, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException}]]
[DEBUG] com.iocs.portal.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
[DEBUG] com.iocs.portal.security.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Comment: Seems like your server denies the request and sends an authorization error. Make it work for chrome first, then you would know better what the problem is in IE9

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by sending the authentication parameters along with the request from front-end. As I was using Auth2 authentication, it was OK to include the token in the request.